# User not found Error in Ranger Kylin plugin integration

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh, hortonworks-sandbox, kylin, apache-ranger

I am working on Ranger Kylin plugin installation. And I have completed the plugin installation. Ranger is showing Kylin services and policy on its web page. Ranger admin UI is successfully connected with kylin and policy cache json file in etc/ranger is also created. I have also updated kylin.properties file with "kylin.server.external-acl-provider".

Now, when I create a new user using ranger admin UI and give permission to this user on kylin policy.  After that using the same user I am not able login in Kylin GUI.

I have checked logs and it says User not found. Only spring security code is in exception, No ranger code stack trace is available in exception. I guess, Kylin is not switched to ranger auth.

Do I need to add more properties in kylin.properties to switch on Ranger policy? So, Kylin can authenticate using ranger users?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Ranger Plugin for Kylin only manages the authorization, not authentication. That means, the newly added user in Ranger, still not exists in Kylin. You can manually add that in Kylin user repository.